# Remove In-App Billing record from google test account for Testing again

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have created google play test account for testing In-App billing, but the problem is that when i purchase the item and then uninstall app and then install it again on that device and test for In-App billing it gives response that the app is already purchased. So how can i remove the old record of purchasing from test account on Google Developer Console.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since your product is Managed Product by Google therefore your purchased item is already connected to your google account. The best way to get around is to use another gmail account or create a new gmail that you can use to test again.

Secondly, It's always better to test your purchase with static response i.e **"android.test.purchased"** in your product ID field. If everything goes fine here then try it on Alpha/Beta mode in developer console.